# Image inside <ng-content *ngIf="false"> still causes network request

Tags: angular

Create a simple Angular app with `ng new`. Then create `src/test.component.ts` with the content:

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
@Component({
  selector: "test",
  template: `<ng-content *ngIf="false"></ng-content>`
})
export class TestComponent {}
```

Add it to `src/app.module.ts` and update your `src/app.component.html` file to use this new component (note that I modified the img src to point to a networked image, not a base64 encoded one):

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
  <test>
    <img width="300" alt="Angular Logo" src="https://duckduckgo.com/assets/logo_homepage.normal.v107.svg">
  </test>
</div>
```

When you run the app, you should *not* see an image on the screen, but yet if you open up the developer tools under networking, you still see the image network request.

Why is this image being loaded even though the DOM doesn't have an `<img>` tag? How can I make this not happen, or is this a bug?

The reason I think this behavior is weird is because if you skip the `<ng-content>` w/ custom component and do a regular `<ng-container>` or `<div>` with an `*ngIf="false"` and the image inside, you will not get any network requests until the content is displayed.

You can access the full source code [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W6fx2qzTfrXXx5XQM5eHL0RtRBbA48Je/view).

Comment: That's by design. View children are always created regardless if they are projected or not. Wrapping it into `ng-template` should do the trick

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44929726/1009922).