# ng-content inside ng-template always creates content even if the template is not rendered

Tags: angular, angular2-template, ng-template, angular2-ngcontent

I am facing a strange bug with a `ng-content` wrapped in a `ng-template`.

Let's say I have a component `inner-component` which I display within a `outer-component`:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="condition" [ngTemplateOutlet]="test"></ng-container>
<ng-template #test>
    <inner-component></inner-component>
</ng-template>
```

If `condition=false`, then, as expected, my `inner-component` is never created by Angular (when debugging, `ngOnInit()` is never called).

Now, if instead I have my outer component as:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="condition" [ngTemplateOutlet]="test"></ng-container>
<ng-template #test>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</ng-template>
```

and, still with `condition=false`, I write:

```
<outer-component>
    <inner-component></inner-component>
</outer-component>
```

Then, to my surprise, the `inner-component` is created, even if it is never rendered. This is a problem for me because the inner-component (a 3rd party component which I can't modify) really does need to be created when it is rendered in the app.

Can you think of a workaround I could use on the outer component to avoid creating the ng-content, (while still using transclusion obviously - the first solution is not an option).

Comment: perhafs you wrote in .ts condition="false" (a string) -well, generally this happens when received data from a service and is a string- or you has a template reference variable called condition

Comment: Oh, I get what you're doing now!

You don't want the `inner` component to be initialized on the outside of outer, but from within the `outer-component`'s template by using a conditional around `ng-content`.

Comment: Yes, after much head-scratching, I think this is actually the same problem as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44929726/angular4-ng-content-gets-built-when-ngif-is-false except I cannot use the proposed solution...

Answer (score 1):

You could move the template to the parent component.

```
<app-outer>
    <ng-template #test>
        <app-inner></app-inner>
    </ng-template>
</app-outer>
```

And in your outerComponent get a child reference to the template

```js
@ContentChild('test') testTemplate: TemplateRef<ElementRef>;
```

Outer html

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="condition" [ngTemplateOutlet]="testTemplate"></ng-container>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nhvkf3?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Hmm, no my inner-component is in the right place, within the `test` template. This `test` template is supposed to be rendered within the first ng-container if the condition is `true`

Comment: Facepalm. Update answer, I think this is why.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but I wish there were a way to keep the current API for my outer-component (that is avoid the ng-template wrapping the inner-component)

Comment: @EricLeibenguth Couple things you could also consider are dynamic component loading, or making custom structural directives. I've struggled with this same issue before also.